# groovy - displaying a String by using <br>

Tags: html, groovy

I have a String that contains several values to be displayed in a table

```
def myString = "123,234;12904,1989,8709,6745"
```

I replace each value by a link

```
<td>${myString.replaceAll(/[0-9]+/) { m ->  '<a href="../mylink>'+m+'</a>'}}</td>
```

The result is:

```
123,234;12904,1989,8709,6745,....
```

I constated the string can be very long, so I added a `'br'` after each value:

```
<td>${myString.replaceAll(/[0-9]+/) { m ->  '<a href="../link>'+m+'<br></a>'}.replaceAll(",","")}</td>
```

The result is:

```
123
234
12904
1989
8709
6745
...
```

The result does not suit me.

The best solution for me is to add a `'br'` after the third value to have something like:

```
123,234;12904
1989,8709,6745
```

Is there a possibility to have this display from the code I already have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
myString.findAll( /[0-9]+/ )                       // Extract numeric elements
        .collect { "<a href='../mylink'>$it</a>" } // Create a link for each
        .collate( 3 )                              // Group them into 3s
        .collect { it.join() + '<br>' }            // Join each 3 with a <br>
        .join( '\n' )                              // Then join all the lines together
```

Or

```
myString.findAll( /[0-9]+/ )                       // Extract numerics
        .collect { "<a href='../mylink'>$it</a>" } // CReate a  link for each
        .collate( 3 )*.join()                      // Group by 3s and join them together
        .join( '<br>' )                            // Then split each by a <br>
```

Comment: Thanks, I also added a comma to separate values: <code>$it, </code>

Comment: Might be bette to keep it as it was, and change the last 2 lines to `.collate( 3 )*.join( ',' ).join( ',<br>' )` to keep the commas out of the links :-)